# Spliting interval with closed countable set of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have a statement that I was not able to prove or disprove. Say we have a countable *closed* set $A$ of real numbers laying between $0$ and $1$ and also including $0$ and $1$. Then let's define following set of intervals:
$$I(A) = \{ (a, b) : a < b, a \in A, b \in A, \forall c \in A \Rightarrow c \notin (a, b) \}$$
I.e. set of all intervals between nearby points of $A$. Note that each number in $A$ is not necessary a boundary of an interval included in $I$ (example : if $A = \{0, 1, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 3, \frac 1 4, ...\}$ then $0$ is not a boundary of any interval included in $I$).

Obviously $I$ is countable or finite (since $A$ is countable and you can match each interval from $I$ to it's lower boundary). That means we can now sum lengths of all those intervals and get a finite or a converging infinite sum:
$$s(I) = \sum _{(a, b) \in I} b - a$$
If the sum is infinite then we can prove that it's converging since $b - a$ is always positive and any partial sum is $\leq 1$.

My question is following: Is $s = 1$ always true? If so then how do I prove that? And if not then what is the case when $s \neq 1$?

Here is what I have found yet:

- $A$ actually has to be closed in order for my hypothesis to survive. If $A$ could be not closed then we could have taken $A = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1] \implies I = \emptyset, s = 0$
- $\forall c \in [0, 1], c \notin A \Rightarrow \exists (a, b) \in I, c \in (a, b)$. We can prove this by setting $a = \sup{A \cap [0, c]}$ and $b = \inf{A \cap [c, 1]}$. $a \in A$ and $b \in A$ since $A$ is closed.
- Let $A'$ be the set of all limit points of $A$. Then $s(I(A')) = s(I(A))$. This is rather hard to prove and it's not a part of the question so I won't prove it here unless anybody asks.

Comment: See [this](https://planetmath.org/proofthattheouterlebesguemeasureofanintervalisitslength) proof.  It's a standard step in development of Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the proof thanks to @Chad K comment suggesting to look at [this prove](https://planetmath.org/proofthattheouterlebesguemeasureofanintervalisitslength).

Since every partial sum of interval lengths is $\leq 1 \implies s \leq 1$ it suffices to prove that $s \geq 1$ or $\forall \epsilon > 0 \Rightarrow s \geq 1 - \epsilon$. To prove that let's define a new set of open intervals:

$$I^* = \left\{\left(a - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}, a + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}\right) : a \in A, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$$

Where $n$ is natural number ($\geq 1$) attached by a bijection to respective $a \in A$ (this is possible since $A$ is countable).

$$s(I^*) = \sum_{(a, b) \in I^*}(b - a) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\epsilon}{2^n} = \epsilon$$

Let $I' = I \cup I^*$. As I showed in the question $x \in [0, 1], x \notin A \implies \exists (a, b) \in I: x \in (a, b)$. And obviously $x \in A \implies \exists (a, b) \in I^*: x \in (a, b)$. Thus $[0, 1] \subseteq I'$. And since we proved that $I'$ fully covers $[0, 1]$ according to Heine-Borel theorem there is a finite subset $I_n \subset I'$ that also covers $[0, 1]$. Here is the proof:

Let's assume such a finite $I_n$ does not exist. Thus $[0, 1]$ requires infinitely many intervals of $I'$ to be fully covered. Then we can divide the segment $[0, 1]$ into two half:  $[0, \frac 1 2]$ and $[\frac 1 2, 1]$. Obviously at least one of them also requires infinitely many intervals to be covered. We choose that segment and divide it again and again we choose the half that requires infinitely many intervals. Continuing this process we get a converging series of segments that converges say to $c$. Since $c$ also lies in an interval $(a, b) \in I'$ and that interval is open there should be a segment in our series $[c, d] \subset (a, b)$. But that contradicts the fact that each segment of our series requires infinitely many intervals of $I'$ to be covered. Thus proving that such a finite $I_n$ indeed exists.

Since $I_n$ is finite and it covers $[0, 1]$ it's quiet obvious that $s(I_n) \geq 1$. Then $s(I') \geq s(I_n) \geq 1$. Also $s(I') = s(I) + s(I^*) \implies s(I) = s(I') - s(I^*) \geq 1 - \epsilon$. And that proves my theorem!

Answer (score 0):

Let $U = \bigcup_{(a,b) \in I} (a,b)$ be the union of the intervals. By the definition of $I$, no $c \in A$ can be a member of any of these intervals, so $U\cap A = \emptyset$. But you've also shown that for all $c \notin A$, there is some $(a,b) \in I$ with $c \in (a,b)$. This means that $U\cup A = [0,1]$.

If $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure, then $\lambda(U) = \lambda([0,1]\setminus A) = 1$ since $A$ is countable.
Since the intervals in $I$ are pairwise disjoint, $1 = \lambda(U) = \sum_{(a,b)\in I} \lambda((a,b)) = \sum_{(a,b)\in I} b-a$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know the proof that $\lambda([0,1]\setminus A)=1$ if A is countable. And I found and posted my own proof which is more detailed.

Comment: All countable sets have Lebesgue measure $0$. This is easy to show because the outer measure is the infimum over sums of the lengths of countable collections of intervals covering the set. And since $A$ is countable, it can be indexed $\{a_n\}$ and covered with the intervals $(a_n - \epsilon 2^{-n}, a_n + \epsilon 2^{-n})$, the sum of whose lengths goes to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. So $$1 = \lambda([0,1]) =\lambda([0,1]\setminus A) +\lambda(A) = \lambda([0,1]\setminus A) + 0$$